# Could not connect to wifi hotspot when ufw is enabled

Tags: wireless, 22.04, ufw, hot-spot

I have a wifi hotspot with Ubuntu 22.04.

Without UFW enabled, my phone connects just fine and can browse the internet. With UFW enabled, I could not connect.

Comment: Most likely UFW doesn't allow dhcp and dns requests.

Comment: is there a way to configure it?